# Unable to compile simple C# file with mono's dmcs

Tags: ubuntu, mono, dmcs

I'm trying to use dmcs to compile a simple C# source file. This is the source file:

```
using System;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I try to compile it with `dmcs MainFile.cs`, but I the the error:

> Could not load signature of Mono.CSharp.Driver:Create due to:
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception
>   has occurred.     [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.

I can compile it just fine with `gmcs`, but I want `dmcs` to get `C#4` features.

Does anyone know how to solve that problem?

I'm running mono 2.10.5 on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: sounds like you have a broken mono installation. I never had much luck with the ubuntu versions of mono. You are often best off building it yourself from the source tarballs on debian/ubuntu

Comment: Well, I found out it doesn't really matter, so I prefer not to start installing things without the package manager. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that gmcs also supports C#4.0, so it doesn't really matter...